# in mips,user presses any key, output a random number between 0 and 100

Tags: random, numbers, mips

here what I did, not working.

```
.data

prompt:     .asciiz     "\nrandom number: "

.code

rd:
            la      $a0,prompt

            syscall $print_string

            syscall $read_int

            li  $a1,100

            syscall $random

            move    $a0,$v0

            syscall $print_int

            b       rd
```

anyone can help fix the mistake?, and I really have no idea for "press any key output a random number", when I run the code, only after press "enter",it gave me a number.

Answer (score 0):

All the input syscalls are line-buffered. To do what you are asking you will probably have to use memory-mapped I/O. An example of how to do this with the SPIM simulator is [here](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs315/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch14s03.html)

Comment: thanks for the link,I am reading that,but I want to print a random from 0 to 100, it just gave me a real random number like 5049,34059,30945......, how do I fix that?

Comment: Best to just take the modulus of 100.